# How to make POST request with axios and React State Hook

Tags: reactjs, async-await, axios

How can I properly make the following POST request?

```
const postWorkout = async () => {

    setCompletedWorkout({
      date: 31,
      day: workout.mains[0].day,
      exercises: completedExercises
    })
    
    try {
      await axios.post('/history', completedWorkout)
    } catch(error) {
      throw error
    }
  }
```

I believe that it makes the request before completedWorkout is actually set as shown in the DB by an empty document:
[image: Empty document in MongoDB after POST request]

Comment: Do you want to make the request after updating `completedWorkout`?

Comment: State updates do not happen immediately. `completedWorkout` is a const (or should be), and is not capable of changing until the function is called **next render**. You would either need to move the post into a `useEffect` or use the new object directly.

Comment: Yes I do! The only workaround I've tried so far is to have them in different functions and calling the setCompletedWorkout function first then calling the function to make a request. However, this is probably not the most efficient way... I'd like for them to be in the same function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming `setCompletedWorkout` is setting it to the state.
If so, you will need to wait for that to be completed since setting a state is async.
You can do this by using `useEffect` like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
   // POST HERE
}, [completedWorkout]);
```

The code inside `useEffect` will execute once your `completedWorkout` is set

Comment: Thanks! I already have a useEffect in place that gets data on the first render. Is it possible to have multiple useEffects or just one?

Comment: There's no limit to the number of `useEffects` you can have.

Comment: Is there a way for the useEffect to be invoked ONLY when the workout is set? I have my dependency array as [workout] but according some documentation, it is being invoked on the first render as well? So it actually posts twice, once when it is first rendered and then a second time when setWorkout is called

Comment: @nalanart inside the useEffect, maybe you could add a check to make sure completedWorkout is not empty/null